# Let $G$ be a graph such that $\chi(G - x - y) = \chi(G) - 2$, for all distinct vertices $x,y$. Prove that $G$ is complete.

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, graph-connectivity

I understand that it's a complete graph because $\chi(K_n) = n$ (by Brooks theorem), so when we start cutting vertices, with $K_{n-1}$ we will have $\chi(K_{n-1}) = n-1$. 
My question is how would I prove this, I keep getting to a road block on just how to say it in a mathematical sense.

Comment: Try proving the converse: If $G$ is not complete, then $\chi(G-x-y)\not=\chi(G)-2$. (Hint:  Let $x,y$ be two nonadjacent vertices, and color $G-x-y$ with $c$ colors. Do you really need $c+2$ colors to color $G$?)

Comment: Thank you for the perspective, you have cleared it up, also thank you for the introduction to clean math haha

Comment: It's also a neat problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $G$ is not a complete graph. So there exist two vertices, say $x$ and $y$ such that x is not connected to $y$. Let $f : V (G − x − y) → [χ(G) − 2]$ be a proper $(χ(G) − 2)$-coloring of $G$. Create a new color and assign it to both $x$ and $y$ to create a proper $(χ(G)−1)-$ coloring of $G$, a contradiction.